# Rename each file an incrementing integer

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management, rename, filenames

I have a directory of mp3 files, sorted in order of `Date created`:

```
newest.mp3
new.mp3
old.mp3
older.mp3
oldest.mp3
```

I want to rename each file in this directory with a new name including an integer value that increases for each file (starting at the newest file):

```
newest.mp3 --> new_name_1.mp3
new.mp3    --> new_name_2.mp3
old.mp3    --> new_name_3.mp3
older.mp3  --> new_name_4.mp3
oldest.mp3 --> new_name_5.mp3
```

How can I do this automatically (without needing to manually `rename` each file)?

Specifically, I'm looking for a command to essentially do this:

```
sort each file by date created
i = 1
for each fil in dir:
    rename file: new_name_$i++.mp3
```

Comment: Have you tried a batch looping with `for` on `dir /od` using an incrementing counter via `set /a`?

Comment: No. I haven't done scripting / programming on windows before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that

```bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1"
for /f "delims=*" %%f in ('dir /b /o:-d /tc *.mp3') do (
    ren %%f new_name_!count!.mp3
    set /a count+=1
)
```

- `dir /b`: output the files in bare format (only file names)
- `/o:-d`: sort by date, newest first
- `/tc`: sort using creation date. You may want to change C to A or W for access time and modification time

Then each line of the output is read using `for /f`

To make it work for any directory, change the loop to

```bat
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc "%1\*.mp3"`)
```

and pass the directory in the first parameter

To get help for any commands in Windows cmd, just use `/?`

- [`for /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble running this as a batch file. I've saved the code to a `.bat` file in the directory above, and pasted the full `C:\Users\...` path. After running `> script.bat` it says `C:\Users\...` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program of batch file

Comment: `> script.bat` is not the way to run the script because `>` is a redirection operator. And what do you mean by pasted the full path? Where did you pasted? This one will run with the files in the current directory, if you want to rename files in another directory then a small change need to be done

Comment: The issue was I didn't have the batch file in the desired directory. It's working now. Thanks very much!

Comment: However, the batch file is no longer in the directory. Has that been renamed to a `.mp3` file as well?

Comment: yes, it's the newest/smallest file. I've added `*.mp3` to the dir command so it excludes the batch file

Answer (score 0):

While this can be scripted, in the comments to your question you dont do scripting.

There are a number of free file renaming utilities that can accomplish what you want.  [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is one, of many you can search for.

Comment: I've updated the question to illustrate what I'm looking for